# click on ListView's last item doesn't work unless I click an item first. Clicks stacked?

Tags: android, listview, click, footer

this is the weirdest bug I've ever found and I am unable to fix it. I'm using an external library called android-binding to implement my application. I've contacted one of the developers of this library, he debugged my project and he thinks the bug is not related to his library.

I have a ListView showing tasks from a certain month. The view has a button to load tasks from previous month (from now on, LoadPrevious) and a footer to load tasks from next month (from now on, LoadNext). This external library lets you set an attribute binding:onclick on the layout views, so when the user clicks the view it automatically calls a Command placed in the code.

If I click LoadNext, the function works fine the first time. From here on, everytime I click LoadNext it does nothing, the function isn't called. If then I click on LoadPrevious, all the clicks I did on LoadNext are executed, like if clicks were stacked or something like that.

But it gets more weird. If I click an item of the list (the onClick function doesn't need to do anything, just clicking the item) then LoadNext works fine. I tried to simulate a click from code (ListView->performItemClick, setSelection, setChecked), but it's still not working.

Does anybody know if there is a reason why clicks on Views could be stacked or something like that?

EDIT: The project code isn't simple. I'll just place here the code related to the failing functionality, skipping all the other functionalities of this activity, although I think that some other of these functionalities could have something to do with the error.

This is the code of the Command that's not working:

```
public final CursorCollection<TaskItem> TaskList = new CursorCollection<TaskItem>(TaskItem.class); // Binded to the ListView (like an Adapter). Related to the external library

public final Command LoadNext = new Command(){
    @Override
    public void Invoke(View arg0, Object... arg1){
        monthListEnd++;
        if(monthListEnd==12){
            monthListEnd=0;
            yearListEnd++;
        }
        listTitle=monthName[monthListStart]+" "+yearListStart+" to "+monthName[monthListEnd]+" "+yearListEnd;
        fillList();
    }
};

//Fills the ListView.  
public void fillList(){
        int daysLastMonth = numberOfDays[monthListEnd];
        if(monthListEnd==1 && yearListEnd%4==0 && (yearListEnd%100 != 0 || yearListEnd%400 == 0)) daysLastMonth++;
        Cursor c = model.getTasks(1, monthListStart, yearListStart, daysLastMonth, monthListEnd, yearListEnd);
        if (c.getCount() == 0) ListEmpty.set(true);
        else ListEmpty.set(false);
        mContext.startManagingCursor(c);
        TaskList.setCursor(c);
}
```

This is TaskItem class:

```
public class TaskItem extends RowModel{ 
    public final StringField Id = new StringField("id"); 
    public final StringField Id_local = new StringField("id_local"); 
    public final StringField Name = new StringField("name"); 
    public final DateField StartDate = new DateField("start_date"); 
    public final DateField EndDate = new DateField("end_date"); 
    public final StringField Status = new StringField("status"); 
}
```

I've found out some interesting things. If I comment the line "TaskList.setCursor(c);" from the fillList() function it works. But if I let that line uncommented and I delete the tabs from my view (the layout has two tabs, and the second one has the list) it works too. That is, if I use both things (tabs and setCursor) it doesn't work, but if I delete one of them it does work.

But that doesn't end there. I created a simplified version with my project with tabs and setCursor but without context menu in the list, without options menu in the layout and without a SyncAdapter running on background and it works too. It's like this error only happens when a set of things are working together, and two of these things are the setCursor and the tabs. Like I said, weirdest bug I've ever found.

Comment: I don't think the click on Views are stacked in android.. maybe it's a implementation issue.. could you post your code here?

Comment: I placed some code and a couple of things I just discovered.